# Specific fields using cut or Awk

Tags: linux, bash

How to cut a specific field from a line?

The problem is I can't use `cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14`, since the field changes.

Let's say I have a file called /var/log/test, and one of the lines inside the file looks like this :

```
Apr 12 07:48:11 172.89.92.41 %ASA-5-713120: Group = People, Username = james.robert, IP = 219.89.259.32, PHASE 2 COMPLETED (msgid=9a4ce822)
```

I only need to get the Username and Time/Date ( please note columns keep changing, that's why I need to match the  Username = james.robert and Apr 12 07:48:11

When I use :

```
grep "james" /var/log/tes | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

Doesn't work for me. So it has to match the username and prints only username and data/time. Any suggestions?

Ok so when I use this :

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '$12~/username/{print $1,$2,$3,$12}' /var/log/test
```

but it works for some users, but not the others, because fields keep moving.

The sample output of this command is :

Apr 12 06:00:39 james.robert

But when I try this command on this username, it doesn't work. See below :

here is another example that with the above command doesn't show anything:

```
Apr  8 12:16:13 172.24.32.1 %ASA-6-713228: Group = people, Username = marry.tarin, IP = 209.157.190.11, Assigned private IP address 192.168.237.38 to remote user
```

Comment: Is the first field always the date?

Comment: yes it is . but the username keeps moving.

Comment: If you could please post more than one record as an example. You've been asked by a couple of us. We are shooting in the dark and are not able to guess at your edge cases.

Comment: Ok, i added another line from that file.

Comment: The sane solution would be to move to a properly structured format like JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your file is structured consistently

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $1,$2,$3,$12}' file

Apr 12 07:48:11 james.robert
```

if you need to match the username, using your sample input

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' '$12~/james/{print $1,$2,$3,$12}' file
Apr 12 07:48:11 james.robert
```

**UPDATE**

OK, your spaces are not consistent, to fix change the -F

```
$ awk -F' +|,' '{print $1,$2,$3,$12}' file

Apr 12 07:48:11 james.robert
Apr 8 12:16:13 marry.tarin
```

you can add the /pattern/ to restrict the match to users as above.  Note the change in -F option.

> `-F' +|,'` sets the field separator to spaces (one or more) or comma,
>   the rest is counting the fields and picking up the right one to print.
>   `/pattern/` will filter the lines that matches the regex pattern, which can > be constrained to certain field only (e.g. 12) by `$12~/pattern/`

if your text may contain mixed case and you want to be case insensitive, use `tolower()` function, for example

```
$ awk -F' +|,' 'tolower($12)~/patterninlowercase/{print $1,$2,$3,$12}' file
```

Comment: It's giving me different results. And also where does it match the username?

Comment: please post, what you expect to see and what you got.

Comment: Ok this works a lot better but there are still some issues. Here is the thing, it's not possible to get the date and username and date in a different way? because it works for 2, 3 users, but when I type 4th user with a different name it doesn't show anything. Is there any other mechanism?

Comment: There are many ways, but we're shooting in the dark here, please update your original question with the cases you're testing and post the expected output.

Comment: the user that didn't work, her name is saved like this in this file :
Apr  8 12:51:45 172.24.32.1 %ASA-6-713273: Group = people, Username = marry.tarin, IP = 189.157.111.9, Deleting static route for client address: 192.168.12.14

Comment: So for james I've got : Apr 12 07:48:11 james.robert. 
but for mary I've got no result ! and I showed you how her records are saved in the file , please see it again:
Apr 8 12:51:45 172.24.32.1 %ASA-6-713273: Group = people, Username = marry.tarin, IP = 189.157.111.9, Deleting static route for client address: 192.168.12.14

Comment: I can't read it from the command line.  Please update the input file with more records especially the ones not working for you so that we can see what the format variations are.  I don't know how to say this more clearly.   Don't post the data here as comments post the data on the original question in a formatted way.

Comment: Ok, i updated my question and said your command works for james. but doesn't work for mary. Does this help? I posted another sample line for mary

Comment: This is great ! I wish I knew how your command is working though lol Thanks a lot

Comment: Just as of curiosity, is it possible to add something so this command will be case insensitive? so the username works with both lower & upper case? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't come back with any results.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^([A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*(Username = [^,]*).*/\1 \2/g' file
```

Comment: It gave more more info than I needed. Also where does it try to match the username? Because fields keep moving..

Comment: @RomiKajaki, `(Username = [^,]*)` will match username and the data will be grouped. You can refer this group later in the substitution using `\2` (2nd group).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` to delimit by comma and then use `substr()` and `length()` to get at the pieces you care about:

```
awk -F"," '{print substr($1,1,15), substring($3, 13, length($3)-12)}' /var/log/test
```

Comment: it gives me an error. Also where does this even try to match the username?

Comment: It doesn't The assumption here is that the placement of the commas are consistent so that your `username = ` field is in the 3rd position.

Comment: Perhaps... it would be helpful if you included more than one record from your log file so we can have some idea of the different formats that these records might be in. The best we can do is code as wide in scope as we can guess at, and hope it catches all of your edge cases. Without seeing differently formatted records though, it's hard to guess at those.

Answer (score 0):

With `gawk`

```
awk '{u=gensub(/.*(Username = [^,]*).*/,"\\1","g",$0);if ( u ~ "james") {print u,$1,$2,$3}}' file
```

Comment: Didn't work. It shows everything ! 
I only need username and date . 
Like : Apr 12 07:48:11 james.robert

Answer (score 0):

The following perl will print the date and username delimited by a tab. Add additional valid username characters to `[\w.]`:

```
perl -ne '
    print $+{date}, "\t", $+{user}, "\n" if
        /^(?<date>([^\s]+\s+){2}[^\s]+).*\bUsername\s*=\s*(?<user>[\w.]+)/
    '
```

Varying amounts a tabs and spaces are allowed.